# Name 'predicted_class' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, confusion-matrix

i try to run confusion matrix codes. before this I'am use

```
 print_confusion_matrix(Y_val_org, model.predict_classes(X))
```

but this function is deprecated then changes to

```
predict_x=model.predict(X) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1.
```

Now i have new error which is cannot show the confssion matrix label.

coding:

```
 def print_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred):
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    print('True positive = ', cm[0][0])
    print('False positive = ', cm[0][1])
    print('False negative = ', cm[1][0])
    print('True negative = ', cm[1][1])
    print('\n')
    df_cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, range(2), range(2))
    sn.set(font_scale=1.4) # for label size
    sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}) # font size
    plt.ylabel('Actual label', size = 20)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label', size = 20)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(2), ['Fake', 'Real'], size = 16)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(2), ['Fake', 'Real'], size = 16)
    plt.ylim([2, 0])
    plt.show()

predict_x=model.predict(X) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)
print(predicted_class)
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'predicted_class' is not defined
```

I dont know where to defined predicted_class and there is still error when i run the codes

Comment: Where does `predicted_class` come from? Is that a typo of `classes_x`?

Comment: sorry i just notice it. 1 More question if i want to print the confusion matrix Does it need to be placed before predict?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess it is typo. Just change `classes_x` with `predicted_class`

```py
predicted_class=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)
print(predicted_class)
```

> Thank you sir, i just notice it. 1 more question if i want to print the confusion matrix. i just need input it before predict or after predict?

For best practice, you could print confusion matrix after predict it.